# HoverIntent ClearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeout, hoverintent

How do I clear the timeout built-in to **[hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)**? I'd like to do it from within the **over** section of the same hoverIntent.

Comment: What do you mean? It looks to already do this clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);

Comment: Yes, the plugin does this inside of itself, but when I'm in the "over" function, I don't have access to "ob". ('ob' is undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Upon further research, I found that the timeout is stored as an attribute of the HTML element hoverIntent was applied to. So in order to clear the timeout do the following.

```
clearTimeout($(this).attr("hoverIntent_t"));
```

Keep in mind however, that each element will have it's own timeout attached to it. So to stop hoverIntent all together, you'll want to do the following:

```
$(this).siblings().each(function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).parent().children().attr("hoverIntent_t"));
});
```