# JQuery clear hoverIntent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I have some items lets say X, Y, and Z. I use `hoverIntent` for the hovering event. Let's say when I hover on X I display a tooltip with such kind of code

```
jQuery('.tooltiper').hoverIntent({
        over: showPopup, 
        timeout: 1000, 
        out: hidePopup
    });
```

So it will be visible for 1 second. What I want is if I hover on Y or Z `hidePopup()` to run for X and clear the timeout of `hoverIntent`, so it won't be visible for 1 second. I tried many things but they don't work.

Anyone has experience about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HoverIntent ClearTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378523/hoverintent-cleartimeout)

Comment: You have 6 unaccepted answers dating all the way back to May this year. If you accept those answers people will be more inclined to help you.

Comment: I would accept answers only if they are really working, otherwise they are not correct answers! Also possible duplicate doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
clearTimeout($(".tooltiper").prop("hoverIntent_t"));
$(".tooltiper").prop("hoverIntent_s", 0);
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(this).stop();` in the `hidePopup` function.